# What are the tables dbo.geometry.columns and dbo.spatial_ref_sys in the SQL database for?

Tags: sql-server, types, geometry, ssms

I discovered the new tables `dbo.geometry_columns` and `dbo.spatial_ref_sys` in my SQL database (see image). It looks like they have been automatically created as I did not do it on purpose. I assume that it is caused by me having created some columns of type `geometry` in some tables and views. Are these automatically created tables which are mandatory for operation with columns of type `geometry`?

I am using "Microsoft SQL Server 2017" with "SQL Server Management Studio v18.4" on "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3".

[image]

Comment: Those look to be user tables for postgis, an open source extension for PostgreSQL. I can't say how they were created in your SQL Server database but you might check the model database to make sure they don't exist there.

Answer (score 1):

From https://alastaira.wordpress.com/ogr2ogr-patterns-for-sql-server/

"After importing any data, OGR2OGR will create two additional tables in your SQL Server database – spatial_ref_sys and geometry_columns, which store metadata about the spatial columns in the tables. These tables can be safely ignored (or deleted) – OGR2OGR will recreate them after each conversion anyway"